# Is Sales Cloud add-on needed to activate person accounts with Service Cloud licence?

Tags: licenses, servicecloud, person-accounts

It is not clear from Salesforce documentation if service cloud licenses are entitled for Personal Account activation by default or whether Sales Cloud add-on is required.

Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's available on Service Cloud and doesn't require an additional Sales Cloud add on.

Here's some links to get you started :

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_person_enable.htm&type=5

and
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/226/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_B2C_implementation_guide.pdf

Comment: Yes. It does say: "Self-Service Portal- As with contacts, person accounts can be enabled as users for a Self-Service portal". Thanks, GXian.